# Django rest framework - API view complains about NoneType response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a ModelViewSet to create objects from parameters received in a POST request. The serialiser looks like this:

```
class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to intercept the request, and perform a check on it (against a method of the model, if it matters) before allowing the creation to continue. In vanilla django forms, I would override the form_valid method, do the check, and then call super().form_valid(...). I am trying to do the same here:

```
class BookingView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DirectBooking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DirectBookingSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        #Perform check here
        super().create(request)
```

This works, in the sense that it creates an object in the DB, but the trace shows an error:

```
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

This seems strange, as I would expect the super().save to return the appropriate response.

I am aware that I will need to return a response myself if the check fails (probably a 400), but I would still like to understand why it is failing here.

Comment: You should **`return`** `super().create(request)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view should return a HttpResponse. In a `ViewSet`, you do not implement `.get(..)` and `.post(..)` directly, but these perform some processing, and redirect to other functions like `.create(..)`, and `.list(..)`.

These views thus should then return a `HttpResponse` (or "friends"), here you call the `super().create(request)`, but you forget to return the response of this call as the result of your `create(..)` version.

You should thus add a `return` statement, like:

```
class BookingView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DirectBooking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DirectBookingSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        #Perform check here
        return super().create(request)
```

Comment: That was dumb of me... Thanks